# Conditional Access - "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden", when specifying includedApplications

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to apply Conditional Access Policies using the API, but bumping into some problems.
The policy below works without issues.

```
{
    "displayName": "TEST - Block Policy: Block All Application access from a non-trusted location",
    "state": "disabled",
    "conditions": {
        "users": {
            "includeUsers": [
                "All"
            ]
        },
        "applications": {
            "includeApplications": [
                "All"
            ]
        },
        "locations": {
            "includeLocations": [
                "All"
            ],
            "excludeLocations": [
                "AllTrusted"
            ]
        },
    },
    "grantControls": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "builtInControls": [
            "block"
        ]
    }
}
```

But if i add a specific application in "inculdeApplications" i get access denied.

```
{
    "displayName": "TEST - Block Policy: Block Azure Management access from a non-trusted location",
    "state": "disabled",
    "conditions": {
        "users": {
            "includeUsers": [
                "All"
            ]
        },
        "applications": {
            "includeApplications": [
                "797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013"
            ]
        },
        "locations": {
            "includeLocations": [
                "All"
            ],
            "excludeLocations": [
                "AllTrusted"
            ]
        },
    },
    "grantControls": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "builtInControls": [
            "block"
        ]
    }
}
: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I can manually add the application in the GUI but I want to do this programmatically.

The SPN has the following API permissions in Graph:

- Directory.ReadAll
- Policy.ReadAll
- Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess
- User.Read

Are there any limitations in the API or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: If you received something like a correlation ID and a timestamp from graph, its good to include that detail. It helps those of us that can review backend logs give a more specific answer than a random suggestion.

Comment: I get this:
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000216: 'client_assertion', 'client_secret' or 'request' is required for the 'client_credentials' grant type.\r\nTrace ID: f497f5f4-8da9-452a-8818-7c770c543400\r\nCorrelation ID: 442313c1-666b-4c23-bd94-3036cf55f479\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-06 08:49:40Z","error_codes":[7000216],"timestamp":"2020-04-06 08:49:40Z","trace_id":"f497f5f4-8da9-452a-8818-7c770c543400","correlation_id":"442313c1-666b-4c23-bd94-3036cf55f479","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000216"}

Answer (score 0):

Think I found an answer.. Looks like the API for the time being only supports Delegated permissions for Conditional Access so using an SPN will not work..

Ref: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/conditionalaccessroot-post-policies.md